# Error in where clause of sql update query

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, where-clause, clause

Why does the sql query

```
UPDATE `singleent` SET `pre_timestamp` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE listingType = 1
```

give error whereas

```
UPDATE `singleent` SET `pre_timestamp` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE 1
```

or

```
UPDATE `singleent` SET `pre_timestamp` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

runs perfectly?

**Edit**:

The column type is timestamp and the error was:

> Truncated incorrect static value: select listingType

Comment: listingType what type is that column? int? nvarchar? and whats the error that you receive?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: the column type is timestamp and the error was ' Truncated incorrect static value: select listingType' @Veljko89

Comment: Please, tag dbms used.

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the backticks and the non-standard `where 1` clause

Answer (score 0):

The Error was due to the listingType being of Type varchar and so it needed the value to be in single inverted commas ''

The query

```
UPDATE `singleent` 
   SET `pre_timestamp` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE listingType = '1'
```

is perfect